# Could not download all repository indexes ppa mssql

Tags: ppa, synaptic, 20.10, mssql

when reloading the Synaptic package I face the below popup msg
[mas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytkyI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have various additional repositories (apart from the main Ubuntu ones) in your list.

I'm also assuming that you've upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10 recently, and then re-enabled all of your old repositories.

...

in the header of snwh/pulp (google search) you will find:

```
This PPA has been deprecated!!! Use ppa:snwh/ppa
```

so you'll be best off removing that repository, and adding the new repository in it's place.  please read [https://launchpad.net/~snwh/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Esnwh/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

on your postgres line from "sources.list", you will need to specify the architecture:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt groovy-pgdg main
```

and you need to look at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list` and remove duplicate lines from those files.  you should be able to just comment them out with a '#'

it would have been easier if you could have copied and pasted the text in that window, rather than send a screenshot.